# Creating a Hive view

Tags: sql, view, hive

I have a Hive UDF named find_distance which calculates the coordinate distance between a pair of lat-long coordinates.
I also have a table containing a list of city names and their respective lat-long coordinates.
So currently if I need to find the distance between two cities, say Denver and San Jose, I need to perform a self join:

```
Select find_Distance(cityA.latitude, cityA.longitude, cityB.latitude, cityB.longitude) from
(select latitude, longitude from city_data.map_info where city = 'Denver') cityA
join
(select latitude, longitude from city_data.map_info where city = 'San Jose') cityB;
```

How would I go about building a view that would accept just the city names as parameters? So in effect I could just use

```
SELECT distance from city_distance where cityA = 'Denver' and cityB = 'San Jose'
```

Comment: Select find_Distance(cityA.latitude, cityA.longitude, cityB.latitude, cityB.longitude) as distance , cityA.city as city1, cityB.city as city2,  from
(select latitude, longitude , city from city_data.map_info ) cityA
join
(select latitude, longitude , city from city_data.map_info ) cityB;
and use follwing to select 
SELECT distance from city_distance where city1 = 'Denver' and city2 = 'San Jose'
If results are not right , can you share data may be 10 rows

Comment: @RavinderKarra I ended up using your suggestion and it worked - you could add it as an answer:)

Answer (score 1):

Try this VIEW:

```
CREATE VIEW city_distance AS
SELECT
  cityA.city as city_from,
  cityA.city as city_to,
  find_Distance(cityA.latitude, cityA.longitude, cityB.latitude, cityB.longitude) as distance
FROM
  (SELECT city, latitude, longitude FROM city_data.map_info) cityA
  CROSS JOIN
  (SELECT city, latitude, longitude FROM city_data.map_info) cityB;
```

Comment: I don't think cross joining a table is a good idea when all you need is two cities.